# No debugging output in console from QT QML app running on android device

Tags: android, c++, qt, debugging, qml

I'm currently trying to start writing an app based on qt and running on android. The only hitch is that I'am not able to receive any debug info from my phone in the *application output* section.

Precisely, after I ran across this issue I retried with the most simple qml app ever, only with a **Component.onCompleted: console.log("started app")** and later tried:

- with an ios simulator
- with an android simulator
- natively on my mac

and all of them worked just fine outputting the right output, but still not with the cross-compile/native android debug.

It is to be noticed that a bunch of warnings are also outputted by the phone but I understood that it isn't relevant in any way with my problem.

Here is the exacte output:

```
W System  : ClassLoader referenced unknown path:
I QtCore  : Start
W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.testandroid-1/lib/arm/libQt5Network.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x13f76
W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.testandroid-1/lib/arm/libQt5Network.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.testandroid-1/lib/arm/libQt5Qml.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x39763
W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.testandroid-1/lib/arm/libQt5Qml.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.testandroid-1/lib/arm/libQt5Gui.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x55743
W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.testandroid-1/lib/arm/libQt5Gui.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.testandroid-1/lib/arm/libQt5Quick.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x4a817
W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.testandroid-1/lib/arm/libQt5Quick.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.testandroid-1/lib/arm/libQt5QuickParticles.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x55d7
W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.testandroid-1/lib/arm/libQt5QuickParticles.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.testandroid-1/lib/arm/libQt5QuickTemplates2.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x2324c
W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.testandroid-1/lib/arm/libQt5QuickTemplates2.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.testandroid-1/lib/arm/libQt5QuickControls2.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x7e21
W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.testandroid-1/lib/arm/libQt5QuickControls2.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example.testandroid/qt-reserved-files/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x8bec
W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example.testandroid/qt-reserved-files/plugins/platforms/android/libqtforandroid.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
I Qt      : qt start
W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example.testandroid/qt-reserved-files/plugins/bearer/libqandroidbearer.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x1711
W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example.testandroid/qt-reserved-files/plugins/bearer/libqandroidbearer.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : /data/app/org.qtproject.example.testandroid-1/lib/arm/libtestandroid.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x7cf
I Adreno  : QUALCOMM build                   : 5457c29, I79fc85766c
I Adreno  : Build Date                       : 03/07/16
I Adreno  : OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.06.00.02
I Adreno  : Local Branch                     : mybranch18600697
I Adreno  : Remote Branch                    : quic/LA.BR.1.3.3_rb2.12
I Adreno  : Remote Branch                    : NONE
I Adreno  : Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
I OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
W Qt A11Y : Could not activate platform accessibility.
W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example.testandroid/qt-reserved-files/qml/QtQuick.2/libqtquick2plugin.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x4de
W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example.testandroid/qt-reserved-files/qml/QtQuick.2/libqtquick2plugin.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example.testandroid/qt-reserved-files/qml/QtQuick/Controls.2/libqtquickcontrols2plugin.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x36b7
W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example.testandroid/qt-reserved-files/qml/QtQuick/Controls.2/libqtquickcontrols2plugin.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example.testandroid/qt-reserved-files/qml/QtQuick/Window.2/libwindowplugin.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x4b2
W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example.testandroid/qt-reserved-files/qml/QtQuick/Window.2/libwindowplugin.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example.testandroid/qt-reserved-files/qml/QtQuick/Templates.2/libqtquicktemplates2plugin.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0xc39c
W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example.testandroid/qt-reserved-files/qml/QtQuick/Templates.2/libqtquicktemplates2plugin.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example.testandroid/qt-reserved-files/qml/QtQuick/Controls.2/Material/libqtquickcontrols2materialstyleplugin.so: unused DT entry: type 0x1d arg 0x2508
W linker  : /data/data/org.qtproject.example.testandroid/qt-reserved-files/qml/QtQuick/Controls.2/Material/libqtquickcontrols2materialstyleplugin.so: unsupported flags DT_FLAGS_1=0x81
I ActivityThreadEui: handleSleeping sleeping=true screenOn=false
```

And here my .pro file:

```
QT += quick
CONFIG += c++11

#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

CONFIG += console
CONFIG+=qml_debug
CONFIG+=debug

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH =

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

---

note: this is from the "simple" app comming preloaded with qt, and it does work well and displays, but nothing comes out of the console.

My pc config: macOS 10.12.6, Imac 27 2013, qt 5.10.0, SDK Version: 26.1.1, NDK Version: 16.1.4479499, jdk1.8.0_40, android API 23.

My phone config: Leeco 2, qualcomm 652, android marshmallow 6.0.1, debugging activated.

---

**UPDATE**

I then tried to change from **console.log** to **console.warn** or **console.info** (which seemed to work in the output I previously tried) and ... magic ... it worked. It may be because it has an higher priority in android ([link](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html)), but it still isn't working as it is supposed to and thus doesn't show a D as prefix but W (console.warn) or I (console.info).

Thank you in advanced for all your ideas.

Comment: Does setting `QT_LOGGING_TO_CONSOLE=1` help?

Comment: Nope, it didn't change anything at all. I still don't get any output. I even restarted qt after changing the environment variable. Should I try reinstalling everything on either windows or linux?